# How to call up a specific variable in a "database" of defined items

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I am writing a database or something similar, where I define certain items as follows:

```
def item1():
    name = "so and so"
    weight = xy
    color = "rainbow"
    return name,weight,color
```

If I call the item1() it will return its name weight and color, and if I call name it will call its name.
Also if I make another item, or any number of them, like

```
def item2():
    name = "and so"
    weight = z
    color = "invisible"
    return name, weight, color
```

I can call their full properties by "itemX()"  (the x states for any item, for the sake of example, and is not part of the code)

But how can I now call up only one property of a specific item when there are more items with the same name variable? For example; how can I specifically call up the weight of item2() if needed?

`print(weight)` gives, naturally, only the first defined variable in the code, so how do I specify that I want that variable of a given specific item? Something like: `print(item2(weight))` or something like that. I know that this example doesn't work, but which does?

Comment: You are approaching this more-or-less completely the wrong way. Look into object-oriented programming and read an introductory Python tutorial; writing a whole bunch of functions that return tuples is not a good approach.

Comment: You should use a container like a `dict` or define your own `class`. You are using functions here, which will not work that way. They do not have those properties... those are *local variables* within that function's scope.

Comment: What's with the down votes? It's a well constructed question - even if the code sucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to use classes or named tuples

```
class Item:
    def __init__ (self, name, weight, color):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.color = color

item1 = Item ("so and so", 42, "rainbow")
```

Then you can access fields via `.` (dot)

```
>>> print (item1.color)
"rainbow"
```

Comment: Okay, and how do I call up the whole item now ? 

This solves perfectly if i need a specific variable, but can i get all variables of a given item, with just one command now?

I need to be able to do both, get the whole item if called upon like that, or a specific variable of it if needed. Is it possible?

Comment: Example I posted is just how to create your Item manually. For your case this highly depends on how the data are stored, if in database, plain text or otherwise. If plain text, then it's csv, json, xml, ...